# confusion with the Servlets

Tags: servlets

I am new to servelts programming. and Just today, I started learning it. and I am a little bit confused concerning

`HttpServletRequest`. it is written in a tutorial that, the class `doGET()` has some methods such  as form "query" data, HTTP request headers, and the client’s hostname.

As far as I understood, the HttpServletRequest is something like a protocol allows the SERVER to 
    receive a request from the CLIENT side. My question is, Why the CLIENT side is interesting in
    knowing something like the client’s host-name or HTTP request headers.

If you found the question is silly please do not vote my question down, because I do not want to lose this account with stack overflow.

Comment: Just FYI, you won't lose your account when questions are downvoted ;-)

Comment: i lost 2 before because of that

Comment: Do you know the basics of the [HTTP Protocol](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http)? It seems like the problem is more a lack of knowledge of the HTTP protocol instead of servlets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all [HttpServletRequest](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) is an interface implemented by your Servlet Container.
 [HttpServlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html) is a convenience class which your Servlet can extend from and get hold of all the HTTP specific methods. [doGet()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#doGet%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29) is one such method to process the [`GET`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) requests.

> HttpServletRequest is something like a protocol allows the SERVER to receive a request from the CLIENT side

[HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) is a [request-response](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request-response) protocol. Your container forms a `HttpServletRequest` object from the actual request received by the Web Server and forwards it to your Servlet's `service()` method.

> Why the CLIENT side is interesting in
>   knowing something like the client’s host-name or HTTP request headers.

If you are talking about Servlets, it is always executed in server side . Hence, methods like [request.getHeader()](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getHeader%28java.lang.String%29) is used by the Servlet to read headers from the request sent by the client. These headers provide some extra information about the request (or response).Many of the headers associated with a request are handled by the server itself. Take, for example, how a server restricts access to its documents. The server uses HTTP headers, and servlets need not know the details. When a server receives a request for a restricted page, it checks that the request includes an appropriate Authorization header that contains a valid username and a password. If it doesn't, the server itself issues a response containing a WWW-Authenticate header, to tell the browser its access to a resource was denied. When the client sends a request that includes the proper Authorization header, the server grants the access and gives any servlet invoked access to the user's name via the getRemoteUser() call.

Read  [HTTP Made Really Easy](http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/), [An Overview of Request Headers](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/Servlet-Tutorial-Request-Headers.html).